# smartparens, to match only parens

Tags: balanced-parentheses, smartparens

In my Emacs, smartparens tries to match square bracket with parenthesis,
indicating a mismatch, as in the following expression:

```
 (modify-syntax-entry ?[ ". 23" table)
                       ^             ^
```

That's quite confusing. How to configure it to strictly match only parenthesis together?